# FFmpeg: what does av_parser_parse2 do?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libav, dji-sdk

When sending h264 data for frame decoding, it seems like a common method is to first call av_parser_parse2 from the libav library on the raw data.

I looked for documentation but I couldn't find anything other than some example codes. Does it group up packets of data so that the resulting data starts out with NAL headers so it can be perceived a frame?

The following is a link to a sample code that uses av_parser_parse2:

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample/blob/master/android-videostreamdecodingsample/jni/dji_video_jni.c

I would appreciate if anyone could explain those library details to me or link me resources for better understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have details, but when looking at an unknown function, it's often useful to look at the function declaration, which can be found here: https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample/blob/master/android-videostreamdecodingsample/jni/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h

Comment: Thank you. The function header description states it "parse(s) a packet." I looked online for explanation of the terminology but with no avail. Also, another thing to note is that the initial raw data was around 8000 bytes, but after going through the said functions, it seems to be around 30K bytes. I am puzzled by this.

Comment: Parsing a packet means that is extracting the data contained in a packet to be in a format that is useable in your program. It makes sense that the output would be bigger because it is essentially extracting the data from the input, which will likely make it bigger as it is not as efficiently packed/compressed.

Comment: I see. I supposed I need to do some testing to check whether NAL header information of the packet stays the same in both cases. Also, when I relayed the parsed data to another device for ffmpeg codec, the result had **lower** latency than unparsed data (the unparsed data resulted in many corrupted video frames). Is this improvement in latency possible? Wouldn't the increase in byte size as well as computation needed to parse data increase the latency instead? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess that the data transfer throughput is fast between the two, while the receiving end decodes less efficiently, so receiving it after parsing is quicker.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like you guessed, *av_parser_parse2()* for H.264 consumes input data, looks for NAL start codes 0x000001 and checks the NAL unit type looking for frame starts and outputs the input data, but with a different framing.

That is it consumes the input data, ignores its framing by putting all consecutive data into a big buffer and then restores the framing from the H.264 byte stream alone, which is possible because of the start codes and the NAL unit types.  It does not increase or decrease the amount of data given to it.  If you get 30k out, you have put 30k in.  But maybe you did it in little pieces of around 1500 bytes, the payload of the network packets you received.

Btw, when the function declaration is not documented well, it is a good idea to look at [the implementation](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/h264_parser.c).

Just to recover the framing is not involved enough to call it parsing.  But the H.264 parser in ffmpeg also gathers some more information from the H.264 stream, eg. whether it is interlaced, so it really deserves its name.

It however does not decode the image data of the H.264 stream.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be correct in saying that performance of av_parser_parse2() would not change whether I am running it on a phone or a computer? I do not know the computation required for this function, but based on the description, it seems like computational time would be minimal.

Comment: @J.S. yes, it is minimal. It basically has to scan every byte once and then has a closer look at some. But it skips most of them, especially the slice data, where the actual encoded frames are located.

Comment: I see. I was wondering about that because there is an increase in latency when streaming parsed h264 data. I thought it might be due to running av_parser_parse2().

Comment: @J.S. it only outputs a packet once it has a full frame, so it has to wait untill a full frame was received. But if decoding doesn't work without av_parser_parse2(), there is no way to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose it wouldn't matter if I run it on a computer then. I suppose it might be possible to use parallel programming to parse multiple frames at a time to increase speed but I am not too sure.

Comment: No, there is nothing to parallelize here. Even to look for the start codes - which could be done separately in each packet - it is not parallelizable to check for a start code crossing packet boundaries.  av_parser_parse2() does not introduce any more delay than the decoder already has, because it just needs a full slice for decoding and for most H.264 streams every frame is contained in just one slice.  You could confirm that ffmpeg uses all CPU cores with its frame and slice level threading.  Your latency might be caused by something else.  Maybe your stream has B frames?

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense. Yes, I have done analysis on the video in the past and noticed that the h264 stream contains a lot of B frames (which I believe cannot alter but I am researching if I can). So it seems like (correct me if I am wrong) the reason why parsing causes latency is because it divides the stream into frames, which will result in more B frames being processed.

Comment: Then I have to correct you :)  The parser does not change the number of B frames.  The parser just makes sure the decoder gets enough data at once. The B frames are created by the encoder.  Frequently one has a sequence of I B B P BB P ... frames.  To encode the first B frame here, the encoder first has to encode the P frame 2 frames after it.  So we already have a latency of 2 frames at the encoder.  Low latency streams often avoid B frames because of this, for example IPPP... where every frame has only references in the past, which introduce no additional latency.

Comment: Btw, what latency are we talking about?  Much more than 2 frames I guess?

Comment: I see. It seems like with unparsed data, the latency is virtually realtime, but with parsed data, the latency is close to 300ms. I have been thinking about multiple reasons (for instance, the parsed data size is too big for UDP packet), but I do not have concrete solution as of now. Thank you so much for the responses. They were very helpful and I have a better understanding now.

Comment: could you specify what is the input and what is the output in the av_parser_parse2 function arguments?

Answer (score 2):

DJI's video transmission does not guarantee the data in each packet belongs to a single video frame. Mostly a packet contains only part of the data needed for a single frame. It also does not guarantee that a packet contains data from one frame and not two consecutive frames.
Android's MediaCodec need to be queued with buffers, each holding the full data for a single frame.
This is where av_parser_parse2() comes in. It gathers packets until it can find enough data for a full frame. This frame is then sent to MediaCodec for decoding.

Comment: Thank you! Would running av_parser_parse2 on a computer instead of a phone have any impact on the overall speed of decoding? Right now, the frames are parsed on the phone and sent to the computer for decoding into image frames. However, I thought I might be able to reduce the latency by receiving the unparsed data in the computer (server) and running av_parser_parse2 in a C script from the server side. Would it not make any difference?

Comment: A PC will probably run this function faster.
In my own app I just send every packet that comes from the DJI SDK directly to the PC and do the rest of the work there.